# Issue when using std::find with an array of std::string

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run this comparator:

```
if (std::find(movements->begin(), movements->end(), commandBuffer) != movements->end())
```

with:

```
const std::string movements[8] = {"north", "south", "east", "west", "n", "s", "e", "w"};
```

where `commandBuffer` is a `std::string`.

On MinGW32 9.2.0, I get the following:

> error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'const char' and
> 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `std::cbegin` and `std::cend`, or change your array into a `std::array`:

```
std::array<const std::string, 8> movements = {"north", "south", "east", "west", "n", "s", "e", "w"};
const std::string commandBuffer = "north";

if (std::find(movements.begin(), movements.end(), commandBuffer) != movements.end())
    std::cout << "Found!" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

movements is a pointer to the array of strings, basically:

```
const std::string* movements;
```

`movements->begin()` is then equal to `(movements[0]).begin()` and points to the **first character of the first string**, not the string itself. So you are iterating over the characters of the first string.

To iterate over the array of strings instead
use `begin(movemens), end(movements)`.

If you were used `std::vector<string> movements` or `std::array<string, N>`, your code would work also.